# How to Validate a strong type view in MVC3 without a model

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, validation

I've got stuck with my project.
The project has 3 layers:

1. Data access with a ado.net data model.
2. A WCF service that retrieve data from de data access ado.net data
   model and sends a serialized class.
3. A MVC web application that connects to a wcf service.

The wcf service has classes with procedures that retrieve data from the other layer (data access layer) and returns to the mvc application (there's no problem with this)
I've created a strong type view (from the wcf service reference) that shows product categories and it does very well buy I don´t know how to validate this view!

I've seen many articles about validation and most of that are using model and data annotations but it's not my case. I found some articles about jquery validations but I've tried and nothing happens... here is the code of the view:

```
@model SkySolutionsMVC3.ProductCategoryServiceReference.CompositeProductCategory
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
}
<h2>
    Edit</h2>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>


@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Product Category</legend>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Enabled)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Enabled)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Enabled)
        </div>
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { id="Name"})
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
        </div>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" name="btnSave" value="Save" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}
<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

Please help! I need some ideas...Thanks.

Comment: The reason nothing happens is because your model metadata is not set to validate properties. You have to let your view know somehow how it needs to be validated. What is the reason you do not want to use data annotation for your validation?

Comment: your question title is but confusing, how a view can become strongly typed if there is no model? also please post your model...

Comment: I don't see why would this question be tagged with WCF?

Comment: @PetarVucetin i personally think that a WCF tag would be correct as people with WCF + MVC3 experience are likely to have come across this same issue and may have advise to offer

Comment: Firs of all, sorry for my english.... Dmitry, I'm not using data annotation because when I create the reference to the wcf service I can instance an object that has all the function needed to retrieve or send data to the DB and in this case I think that a model is not needed (I think). // 3nigma, the view is strongly typed because is based  in a class that is reference through the wcf service reference or at least that was I defined when I created the view.

Comment: ...The view code that I posted before is how the view looks right now, but I tried to add some jquery code in order to validate it like:

$("#form").validate({
        rules: {            
            UserName: {
                required: true,
                minLength: 2,

            }........

something like that.

Comment: Ok, this is the jquery code(am i missing something): 
<pre><code>
    <script type ="text/javascript">
        $().ready(function () {
            $("#frmProductCategory").validate({
                debug: true,
                rules: {
                    Name: {
                        required: true,
                        minlength: 30
                    }
               }
            });
        });
</script>
</code></pre>
An also I added this in the using tag.

@using (Html.BeginForm(null,null,FormMethod.Post, new { id="frmProductCategory"}))

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure wat it is you are after, but if you are saying that you essentially need to control a class you imported from elsewhere, then how about this: write your own class, inherit from the class you are using as a model now and inherit from IValidatableObject,
then either add the appropriate annotations to overridden properties or implement the Validate method, something like this:

```
public class MyClass : SkySolutionsMVC3.ProductCategoryServiceReference.CompositeProductCategory, IValidatableObject
{
    [Required]
    public override string Name
    {
        get { return base.Name; }
        set { base.Name = value; }
    }

    public IEnumerable Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (Name.Length != 5)
        {
            yield return new ValidationResult("Name must be exaclty 5 characters long", new string[]{"Name"});
        }
    }
}
```